# Why is distinct not working as i expect, duplicates are still showing?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, distinct

Here is a picture of the results obtained. As you can see, there are 2 sets of each which are the same

[image]

I have a query and it is returning results which are duplicates. Even when using distinct it still shows the duplicates. The query basically show an item being scanned but the item is scanned twice and i only want to see it once.

```
select distinct trackinglog.Header_ID, Frame_ID, Frame_No, Sash_No,
                User_Name, Status_timestamp, Jobno
from trackinglog 
  Join JOBQUOTEHEADER on trackinglog.HEADER_ID = JOBQUOTEHEADER.HEADER_ID
where status='10000' and status_timestamp>dateadd(-7 day to current_date)
order by status_timestamp
```

Comment: Distinct applies to ALL the selected columns..I could tell you more but I cannot access your link.

Comment: Looks like `Status_timestamp` is DATETIME/TIMESTAMP and contains time part whereas the client shows DATE part of the value only. Also it is possible that either `User_Name` or `Jobno` contains some non-printable chars. Select `HEX()` for all columns additionally and compare them for the rows pair.

Comment: Best add table definitions and sample data from both tables as text in the question